# Multiple SVN Sync processes running on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

While working on a SVN project, I am encountering multiple sync processes running all the time. It causes other process e.g. running tomcat server etc to cause delays. This starts automatically whenever the eclipse is started.

This is how it looks:

[image]

Is there any way i can stop these apart from clicking on the red "Stop" icon individually for all of them, each time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have many other open projects on your workspace? Maybe closing others would solve the issue.

Also with the [subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) plugin, you can manage your sync with SVN.

Comment: No, i have only one project in the workspace at the moment. And subclipse is not the solution either, it is not able to remove multiple instances each time.